# Calculate the transition dipole moments between the 1s inner shell and the high-lying states of a molecule

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

I am trying to calculate the transition dipole moments between the 1s inner shell and the  high-lying states of N2, namely, $<\psi_{1s}|{\bf r}|\psi_{high-lying}>$.

For this, I installed GAMESS (US) and calculated molecular orbitals of N2.
However, I only got HOMO-6 to LUMO+2.
I want LUMO+3, 4, 5... and if possible, 1s.

How can I do this in GAMESS? Or do I need other softwares?

Answer (score 1):

Might have found the option you are looking for. GAMESS controls MO printing with the `NPREO` keyword. If you can specify ranges of orbitals either by their number (e.g. `NPREO(1)=1,10` prints the first 10 orbitals) or relative to the HOMO (e.g. `NPREO(1)=-3,-5` prints from HOMO-3 to LUMO+4). You can also give 3rd and 4th numbers to list the range of orbital energies to print.

These print options are described on p.23 of the [input descriptions](https://www.msg.chem.iastate.edu/gamess/documentation.html) document on the Gordon research group page.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I checked that option but the default value gives all the calculated MOs. Actually, I kind of solved the problem myself. By changing the basis from STO to N311, and added NDFUNC, NPFUNC, DIFFS, DIFFSP options in the $BASIS group, I obtained up to LUMO+62. (although I'm very skeptical of the vailidity of those MOs.)

Comment: @N.Saito What makes you sceptical of the MOs? It may be worth asking another question to try to figure out whether something is wrong with the MOs. Just be sure to include the level of theory and basis set you are using in that new question.

Comment: The energies of the higher LUMO orbitals are too high. (e.g. LUMO+62 has 42.9 a.u. (1167 eV).) Also, these orbitals looks very localized to each nitrogen atom. I will describe the details in another question.